# PayPal: Straightforward ask to pay - get confirmation example and docs (PHP)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I have a list of products on my site.
The way it is implemented on my site is of no importance, lLet's say it is a table with checkmarks. The user selects products to order:

product_1 $4.99

product_2 $4.99    checked

product_3 $3.99   checked

product_4 $4.99

...

Then the user clicks "order".  My PHP script calls something  on PP side, and the user is presented with the "please pay" page (again, on PP side):

product_2    $4.99

product_3    $4.99

...

Total: ...

As you can see, I have sent to PP list of product names, product prices AND some hidden field called "transaction id", that I will use later to identify the payment, it is a value generated by me.

The user pays, and it triggers the WebHook (IPN?) from PP side, calling another PHP script on my side. It passes payment status (success) and transaction id.
Upon receiving it, I will know that the user purchased these items.

That's it. I need to know if this is possible and a sample code, because PP dev docs are not very beginner friendly.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [standard PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/). Its sample backend routes are in node.js for example purposes.  Implement the backend routes in PHP instead.  Your own "transaction_id" (you should call it something else), if unique and never used before for a completed transaction on your PayPal account, should be set as the v2/checkout/order's `invoice_id` value.

Comment: I have my own shopping cart that calculates total amount to pay (before taxes) and I want to send this total and transaction id (that I will use to identify payment) and receive back an IPN with transaction id. I believe this should only require PHP on my side, no node.js or any PP specific tools. Am I correct?

Comment: Follow the guide in the link. The sample code given is in node.js.  Implement the backend in PHP instead. Do not use IPN.